# save unlimited data to sql database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I would like to know how its possible to store 1000 or more images and be able to access them when you log in to your account.

I tried doing it with database and link them to your email so that every time you log in your profile will show up. I found it difficult to do. I didn't want to create tables for each image.

What other way is their to store unlimited data without having to create a table? Just link email to be able to access data.

Comment: There is no such thing as 'unlimited'. Your server will run out of storage.

Comment: thank you i didnt know that

Comment: Saving BLOB data directly to your SQL table is generally a bad idea, I'd recommend saving it to some file location on your server, or even saving it to some fast external storage (maybe amazon s3).  Then in your SQL store the link to that image, that way your indexes on your db will not become extremely large when querying!   Also you cannot store unlimited data, your server will have a capacity of X GB, you should check with your provider what this number actually is.

Comment: Can add a description of your table so we can direct you more concisely?  My knee jerk inference (after reading the answer already posted) is that you need two things: an auto increment primary key in your table, and a way to avoid file name duplication when you write the images to the file system.

Answer (score 0):

I hope i do not misunderstand your question, but can you not store your 1000 images on your server and save the file direction in a table? Similar to an admin system you could use a php form to upload the images, storing each name into the database, then you can use php and mysqli to retrieve them all into a page or wherever you want them. maybe add keywords to them so you can find them easily with:

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
SELECT * FROM table WHERE keywords LIKE $search_key;
?>
```

Then its just a case of echo.

Hope this helps

Comment: im sorry for the misunderstanding i have the the php code to save the image path to sql. what i want to know is how can i let the user save an unlimited amount of images. and save unlimited file names to a column in mysql i name my column images but it seems i can only save on file name unless i name another column images1 exct.

Answer (score -3):

It's all about 1 to many , you have to be able create not two but three table, one for user one for unique save and one for haw many save as he wants under the unique save. it's all about planning ahead